# Email form within website (not mailto link), which language?

Tags: email, programming-languages

I was wondering what language I need to use in order to create a simple form for emailing an email address on a website.

What language do I need to use in order to make this happen, and does it need to be server-side?  I would imagine so.

Answer (score 3):

Without using a "mailto:" link, this will need to be server side. The language you use may be restricted by the hosting platform, and what languages are supported, or for which support can be added.

Answer (score 1):

Yup server side.. I use a combination of PHP and AJAX to achieve this, with a CAPTCHA system integrated in. $_SESSION variables pass through AJAX calls, hence the CAPTCHA works with AJAX.

Here's the most basic form of a PHP mailer...

```
$to = "info@sonikastudios.com";
    $subject = "Website inquiry from ".$_POST['name'];
    $content = "
    <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
        </head>
    <body>
    <p>
    Name: ".$_POST['name']."<br />Phone: ".$_POST['phone'].'<br />Email: '.$_POST['email'].'<br />Referred By: '.$_POST['referred'].'<br /><br />'.nl2br($_POST['message']).
    '
    </body>
    </html>
    ';

    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    $headers .= 'From: '.$_POST["email"];


    mail($to,$subject,$content,$headers);
    echo "<font color=\"#0c0\">Your message has been sent.</font>";
```

Comment: Look at this documentation too: http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php